# Trusted Web Activity: Is it possible to add file association

Tags: android, file-association, twa

I have been able to successfully create a TWA from the base instructions provided. It links to the website and works as expected.

However, one of the functionalities of the web app is to upload a particular file type (which is a type of zip) and display its content. That functionality too works as expected and one is able to upload the file, say from the downloads directory to the app and it displays.

What would be desirable is: for the user to tap on the file from the directory (say downloads) and it opens in the App. I am aware of the limitations of access a local file in **any** web app. But before I tackle that issue I would like to know if there is a way to associate that file extension (or mime-type) with the app. And more importantly how to at least get the path of the file. In the current setup there is **no custom Activity java code** written. I went by the documentation and put the right settings in the manifest.xml and the site gets loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by implementing [Web Share Target](https://web.dev/web-share-target/) in your Progressive Web App, then [enabling it in our Trusted Web Activity](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/web-share-target).

When using [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap) it will to automatically configure the Trusted Web Activity on `init`.

Comment: Thanks @andreban. Let me try this out and update this post. Tho, I did not use Bubblewrap since the TWA was straight forward, I will look at the Bubblewrap code and incorporate or recreate using Bubblewrap.

Comment: No problem, the blogpost should be enough to help you add it to an existing app.

Comment: I made the changes, @andreban, and was expecting one of the two things to work. Using the Files application when I tap on the document (with ext "umd" in my case), I should see the app either with (1) open with or (2) when I tap on Share. I find neither working. I would like to confirm that this is what is expected to happen. Right?

Comment: Not sure about "Open" in the files app, but it should definitely should work with "Share". I'd be happy to take a loop at the app if you share the APK.

Comment: That would be of great help. How do I share the apk with you? Thanks

Comment: I even downloaded another File Manager app and the share does not throw up "my app". Once I cross that hurdle then I can work on "how to retrieve" the file object content from the POST method of the share_target

Comment: DM me on Twitter (@andreban)

Comment: I have DM'ed you from @UmdProject and shared details. Thanks.